# Why is the Confidence Interval Changing for this Time-Series

Tags: r, time-series, confidence-interval, kalman-filter

I have some R code (which I did not write) and which performs some state space analysis on some time-series. The data itself is shown as dots (scatter plot) and the Kalman filtered and smoothed state is the solid line.

[image: Plot]

My question is regarding the confidence intervals shown in this plot. I calculate *my own* confidence intervals using the standard method (my C# code is below)

```
public static double ConfidenceInterval(
    IEnumerable<double> samples, double interval)
{
    Contract.Requires(interval > 0 && interval < 1.0);

    double theta = (interval + 1.0) / 2;
    int sampleSize = samples.Count();
    double alpha = 1.0 - interval;
    double mean = samples.Mean();
    double sd = samples.StandardDeviation();

    var student = new StudentT(0, 1, samples.Count() - 1);
    double T = student.InverseCumulativeDistribution(theta);
    return T * (sd / Math.Sqrt(samples.Count()));
}
```

Now this will return a single interval (and it does it correctly) which I will add/subtract from each point on the series I have applied the calculation to to give me my confidence interval. But this is a constant and the R implementation seems to change over the time-series.

My question is why is **the confidence interval changing for the R implementation? Should I be implementing my confidence levels/intervals differently?**

Thanks for your time.

---

For reference the R code that produces this plot is below:

```
install.packages('KFAS')
require(KFAS)

# Example of local level model for Nile series
modelNile<-SSModel(Nile~SSMtrend(1,Q=list(matrix(NA))),H=matrix(NA))
modelNile
modelNile<-fitSSM(inits=c(log(var(Nile)),log(var(Nile))),model=modelNile,
method='BFGS',control=list(REPORT=1,trace=1))$model

# Can use different optimisation: 
# should be one of “Nelder-Mead”, “BFGS”, “CG”, “L-BFGS-B”, “SANN”, “Brent”
modelNile<-SSModel(Nile~SSMtrend(1,Q=list(matrix(NA))),H=matrix(NA))
modelNile
modelNile<-fitSSM(inits=c(log(var(Nile)),log(var(Nile))),model=modelNile,
method='L-BFGS-B',control=list(REPORT=1,trace=1))$model

# Filtering and state smoothing
out<-KFS(modelNile,filtering='state',smoothing='state')
out$model$H
out$model$Q
out

# Confidence and prediction intervals for the expected value and the observations.
# Note that predict uses original model object, not the output from KFS.
conf<-predict(modelNile,interval='confidence')
pred<-predict(modelNile,interval='prediction')
ts.plot(cbind(Nile,pred,conf[,-1]),col=c(1:2,3,3,4,4),
ylab='Predicted Annual flow', main='River Nile')
KFAS 13

# Missing observations, using same parameter estimates
y<-Nile
y[c(21:40,61:80)]<-NA
modelNile<-SSModel(y~SSMtrend(1,Q=list(modelNile$Q)),H=modelNile$H)
out<-KFS(modelNile,filtering='mean',smoothing='mean')

# Filtered and smoothed states
plot.ts(cbind(y,fitted(out,filtered=TRUE),fitted(out)), plot.type='single',
col=1:3, ylab='Predicted Annual flow', main='River Nile')

# Example of multivariate local level model with only one state
# Two series of average global temperature deviations for years 1880-1987
# See Shumway and Stoffer (2006), p. 327 for details
data(GlobalTemp)
model<-SSModel(GlobalTemp~SSMtrend(1,Q=NA,type='common'),H=matrix(NA,2,2))

# Estimating the variance parameters
inits<-chol(cov(GlobalTemp))[c(1,4,3)]
inits[1:2]<-log(inits[1:2])
fit<-fitSSM(inits=c(0.5*log(.1),inits),model=model,method='BFGS')
out<-KFS(fit$model)
ts.plot(cbind(model$y,coef(out)),col=1:3)
legend('bottomright',legend=c(colnames(GlobalTemp), 'Smoothed signal'), col=1:3, lty=1)

# Seatbelts data
## Not run:
model<-SSModel(log(drivers)~SSMtrend(1,Q=list(NA))+
SSMseasonal(period=12,sea.type='trigonometric',Q=NA)+
log(PetrolPrice)+law,data=Seatbelts,H=NA)

# As trigonometric seasonal contains several disturbances which are all
# identically distributed, default behaviour of fitSSM is not enough,
# as we have constrained Q. We can either provide our own
# model updating function with fitSSM, or just use optim directly:
# option 1:
ownupdatefn<-function(pars,model,...){
model$H[]<-exp(pars[1])
diag(model$Q[,,1])<-exp(c(pars[2],rep(pars[3],11)))
model #for option 2, replace this with -logLik(model) and call optim directly
}
14 KFAS
fit<-fitSSM(inits=log(c(var(log(Seatbelts[,'drivers'])),0.001,0.0001)),
model=model,updatefn=ownupdatefn,method='BFGS')
out<-KFS(fit$model,smoothing=c('state','mean'))
out
ts.plot(cbind(out$model$y,fitted(out)),lty=1:2,col=1:2,
main='Observations and smoothed signal with and without seasonal component')
lines(signal(out,states=c("regression","trend"))$signal,col=4,lty=1)
legend('bottomleft',
legend=c('Observations', 'Smoothed signal','Smoothed level'),
col=c(1,2,4), lty=c(1,2,1))

# Multivariate model with constant seasonal pattern,
# using the the seat belt law dummy only for the front seat passangers,
# and restricting the rank of the level component by using custom component
# note the small inconvinience in regression component,
# you must remove the intercept from the additional regression parts manually
model<-SSModel(log(cbind(front,rear))~ -1 + log(PetrolPrice) + log(kms)
+ SSMregression(~-1+law,data=Seatbelts,index=1)
+ SSMcustom(Z=diag(2),T=diag(2),R=matrix(1,2,1),
Q=matrix(1),P1inf=diag(2))
+ SSMseasonal(period=12,sea.type='trigonometric'),
data=Seatbelts,H=matrix(NA,2,2))
likfn<-function(pars,model,estimate=TRUE){
model$H[,,1]<-exp(0.5*pars[1:2])
model$H[1,2,1]<-model$H[2,1,1]<-tanh(pars[3])*prod(sqrt(exp(0.5*pars[1:2])))
model$R[28:29]<-exp(pars[4:5])
if(estimate) return(-logLik(model))
model
}
fit<-optim(f=likfn,p=c(-7,-7,1,-1,-3),method='BFGS',model=model)
model<-likfn(fit$p,model,estimate=FALSE)
model$R[28:29,,1]%*%t(model$R[28:29,,1])
model$H
out<-KFS(model)
out
ts.plot(cbind(signal(out,states=c('custom','regression'))$signal,model$y),col=1:4)

# For confidence or prediction intervals, use predict on the original model
pred <- predict(model,states=c('custom','regression'),interval='prediction')
ts.plot(pred$front,pred$rear,model$y,col=c(1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6),lty=c(1,2,2,1,2,2,1,1))

## End(Not run)
## Not run:
# Poisson model
model<-SSModel(VanKilled~law+SSMtrend(1,Q=list(matrix(NA)))+
SSMseasonal(period=12,sea.type='dummy',Q=NA),
KFAS 15
data=Seatbelts, distribution='poisson')

# Estimate variance parameters
fit<-fitSSM(inits=c(-4,-7,2), model=model,method='BFGS')
model<-fit$model

# use approximating model, gives posterior mode of the signal and the linear predictor
out_nosim<-KFS(model,smoothing=c('signal','mean'),nsim=0)

# State smoothing via importance sampling
out_sim<-KFS(model,smoothing=c('signal','mean'),nsim=1000)
out_nosim
out_sim

## End(Not run)
# Example of generalized linear modelling with KFS
# Same example as in ?glm
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
print(d.AD <- data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts))
glm.D93 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, family = poisson())
model<-SSModel(counts ~ outcome + treatment, data=d.AD,
distribution = 'poisson')
out<-KFS(model)
coef(out,start=1,end=1)
coef(glm.D93)
summary(glm.D93)$cov.s
out$V[,,1]
outnosim<-KFS(model,smoothing=c('state','signal','mean'))
set.seed(1)
outsim<-KFS(model,smoothing=c('state','signal','mean'),nsim=1000)

## linear
# GLM
glm.D93$linear.predictor

# approximate model, this is the posterior mode of p(theta|y)
c(outnosim$thetahat)

# importance sampling on theta, gives E(theta|y)
c(outsim$thetahat)

## predictions on response scale
16 KFAS

# GLM
fitted(glm.D93)

# approximate model with backtransform, equals GLM
c(fitted(outnosim))

# importance sampling on exp(theta)
fitted(outsim)

# prediction variances on link scale
# GLM
as.numeric(predict(glm.D93,type='link',se.fit=TRUE)$se.fit^2)

# approx, equals to GLM results
c(outnosim$V_theta)
# importance sampling on theta
c(outsim$V_theta)
# prediction variances on response scale
# GLM
as.numeric(predict(glm.D93,type='response',se.fit=TRUE)$se.fit^2)
# approx, equals to GLM results
c(outnosim$V_mu)
# importance sampling on theta
c(outsim$V_mu)
## Not run:
data(sexratio)
model<-SSModel(Male~SSMtrend(1,Q=list(NA)),u=sexratio[,'Total'],data=sexratio,
distribution='binomial')
fit<-fitSSM(model,inits=-15,method='BFGS',control=list(trace=1,REPORT=1))
fit$model$Q #1.107652e-06

# Computing confidence intervals in response scale
# Uses importance sampling on response scale (4000 samples with antithetics)
pred<-predict(fit$model,type='response',interval='conf',nsim=1000)
ts.plot(cbind(model$y/model$u,pred),col=c(1,2,3,3),lty=c(1,1,2,2))

# Now with sex ratio instead of the probabilities:
imp<-importanceSSM(fit$model,nsim=1000,antithetics=TRUE)
sexratio.smooth<-numeric(length(model$y))
sexratio.ci<-matrix(0,length(model$y),2)
w<-imp$w/sum(imp$w)
for(i in 1:length(model$y)){
sexr<-exp(imp$sample[i,1,])
sexratio.smooth[i]<-sum(sexr*w)
oo<-order(sexr)
sexratio.ci[i,]<-c(sexr[oo][which.min(abs(cumsum(w[oo]) - 0.05))],
+ sexr[oo][which.min(abs(cumsum(w[oo]) - 0.95))])
}

# Same by direct transformation:
out<-KFS(fit$model,smoothing='signal',nsim=1000)
KFS 17
sexratio.smooth2 <- exp(out$thetahat)
sexratio.ci2<-exp(c(out$thetahat)
+ qnorm(0.025) * sqrt(drop(out$V_theta))%o%c(1, -1))
ts.plot(cbind(sexratio.smooth,sexratio.ci,sexratio.smooth2,sexratio.ci2),
col=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),lty=c(1,2,2,1,2,2))

## End(Not run)
# Example of Cubic spline smoothing
## Not run:
require(MASS)
data(mcycle)
model<-SSModel(accel~-1+SSMcustom(Z=matrix(c(1,0),1,2),
T=array(diag(2),c(2,2,nrow(mcycle))),
Q=array(0,c(2,2,nrow(mcycle))),
P1inf=diag(2),P1=diag(0,2)),data=mcycle)
model$T[1,2,]<-c(diff(mcycle$times),1)
model$Q[1,1,]<-c(diff(mcycle$times),1)^3/3
model$Q[1,2,]<-model$Q[2,1,]<-c(diff(mcycle$times),1)^2/2
model$Q[2,2,]<-c(diff(mcycle$times),1)
updatefn<-function(pars,model,...){
model$H[]<-exp(pars[1])
model$Q[]<-model$Q[]*exp(pars[2])
model
}
fit<-fitSSM(model,inits=c(4,4),updatefn=updatefn,method="BFGS")
pred<-predict(fit$model,interval="conf",level=0.95)
plot(x=mcycle$times,y=mcycle$accel,pch=19)
lines(x=mcycle$times,y=pred[,1])
lines(x=mcycle$times,y=pred[,2],lty=2)
lines(x=mcycle$times,y=pred[,3],lty=2)
## End(Not run)
```

The time-series data is:

```
Time, 2.4, 2.6, 3.2, 3.6, 4, 6.2, 6.6, 6.8, 7.8, 8.2, 8.8, 8.8, 9.6, 10, 10.2, 10.6, 11, 11.4, 13.2, 13.6, 13.8, 14.6, 14.6, 14.6, 14.6, 14.6, 14.6, 14.8, 15.4, 15.4, 15.4, 15.4, 15.6, 15.6, 15.8, 15.8, 16, 16, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.4, 16.4, 16.6, 16.8, 16.8, 16.8, 17.6, 17.6, 17.6, 17.6, 17.8, 17.8, 18.6, 18.6, 19.2, 19.4, 19.4, 19.6, 20.2, 20.4, 21.2, 21.4, 21.8, 22, 23.2, 23.4, 24, 24.2, 24.2, 24.6, 25, 25, 25.4, 25.4, 25.6, 26, 26.2, 26.2, 26.4, 27, 27.2, 27.2, 27.2, 27.6, 28.2, 28.4, 28.4, 28.6, 29.4, 30.2, 31, 31.2, 32, 32, 32.8, 33.4, 33.8, 34.4, 34.8, 35.2, 35.2, 35.4, 35.6, 35.6, 36.2, 36.2, 38, 38, 39.2, 39.4, 40, 40.4, 41.6, 41.6, 42.4, 42.8, 42.8, 43, 44, 44.4, 45, 46.6, 47.8, 47.8, 48.8, 50.6, 52, 53.2, 55, 55, 55.4, 57.6                                                                                                
mcycle, 0, -1.3, -2.7, 0, -2.7, -2.7, -2.7, -1.3, -2.7, -2.7, -1.3, -2.7, -2.7, -2.7, -5.4, -2.7, -5.4, 0, -2.7, -2.7, 0, -13.3, -5.4, -5.4, -9.3, -16, -22.8, -2.7, -22.8, -32.1, -53.5, -54.9, -40.2, -21.5, -21.5, -50.8, -42.9, -26.8, -21.5, -50.8, -61.7, -5.4, -80.4, -59, -71, -91.1, -77.7, -37.5, -85.6, -123.1, -101.9, -99.1, -104.4, -112.5, -50.8, -123.1, -85.6, -72.3, -127.2, -123.1, -117.9, -134, -101.9, -108.4, -123.1, -123.1, -128.5, -112.5, -95.1, -81.8, -53.5, -64.4, -57.6, -72.3, -44.3, -26.8, -5.4, -107.1, -21.5, -65.6, -16, -45.6, -24.2, 9.5, 4, 12, -21.5, 37.5, 46.9, -17.4, 36.2, 75, 8.1, 54.9, 48.2, 46.9, 16, 45.6, 1.3, 75, -16, -54.9, 69.6, 34.8, 32.1, -37.5, 22.8, 46.9, 10.7, 5.4, -1.3, -21.5, -13.3, 30.8, -10.7, 29.4, 0, -10.7, 14.7, -1.3, 0, 10.7, 10.7, -26.8, -14.7, -13.3, 0, 10.7, -14.7, -2.7, 10.7, -2.7, 10.7
```

Comment: (+1) 1) I have added the data and the time points. These data are recorded at irregular time periods, so the times at which they are recorded is relevant. I posted it in commas-separated format since someone may want to load the data in some other software instead of getting it from the MASS package. 2) I think you can stick to show the C# code chunk and the last chunk of R code that reproduces the plot. The rest of the code is not even related to this data set. If it is relevant to this question, please explain.

Comment: Your "confidence interval" procedure is not recognizable as a "standard method" for regression. It would seem you are trying to co-opt a procedure (Student t confidence limits for univariate data) and apply it where it is inappropriate.  Perhaps the [Wikipedia article on regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Confidence_intervals) would help clarify the distinction for you.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. I have some series of observations and the formula I have implemented for these should provide the Confidence Interval for the specified level (95% or whatever). Why am I interested in regression here? Sorry I am not a statistician, thanks very much for your time...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are irregularly spaced data, there are even more than one observations at 
a certain time points (e.g. 2 observations at times 8.8, 15.6, 15.8, 6 observations at time 14.6, 4 observations at time 15.4). These are the number of observations at each time:

```
table(mcycle[,1])
#  2.4  2.6  3.2  3.6    4  6.2  6.6  6.8  7.8  8.2  8.8  9.6   10 10.2 10.6   11 
#    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    1    1    1    1    1 
# 11.4 13.2 13.6 13.8 14.6 14.8 15.4 15.6 15.8   16 16.2 16.4 16.6 16.8 17.6 17.8 
#    1    1    1    1    6    1    4    2    2    2    3    2    1    3    4    2 
# 18.6 19.2 19.4 19.6 20.2 20.4 21.2 21.4 21.8   22 23.2 23.4   24 24.2 24.6   25 
#    2    1    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    1    2 
# 25.4 25.6   26 26.2 26.4   27 27.2 27.6 28.2 28.4 28.6 29.4 30.2   31 31.2   32 
#    2    1    1    2    1    1    3    1    1    2    1    1    1    1    1    2 
# 32.8 33.4 33.8 34.4 34.8 35.2 35.4 35.6 36.2   38 39.2 39.4   40 40.4 41.6 42.4 
#    1    1    1    1    1    2    1    2    2    2    1    1    1    1    2    1 
# 42.8   43   44 44.4   45 46.6 47.8 48.8 50.6   52 53.2   55 55.4 57.6 
#    2    1    1    1    1    1    2    1    1    1    1    2    1    1
```

The asymmetry of the confidence interval may reflect different degrees of uncertainty depending on the amount of information around a time point. We may expect narrower confidence intervals at periods where more data are available, and vice versa. The following plot suggests that at periods with higher concentration of observations (e.g. around times 14-15 and 26-27) the confidence interval is narrower.

```
plot(mcycle$times, pred[,3] - pred[,2])
mtext(side = 3, text = "width of confidence interval in the plot posted by the OP", adj = 0)
```

[image: width of confidence intervals]

Also, be aware that even with evenly spaced data we would observe asymmetric 
confidence intervals at the beginning and the end of the sample. This is due to 
the initialization of the Kalman filter (forwards recursions) which typically involves a large variance attached to the initial state vector and the initialization of the Kalman smoother, which is usually initialized with zeros at the end of the sample (backwards recursions). The width of the confidence interval converges to a fixed width.

For illustration, we can take this example where the local-level plus seasonal component model is fitted to a series recorded regularly spaced times. As mentioned before, the confidence interval is symmetric except at the beginning and the end of the sample.

```
require("stsm")
data("llmseas")
m <- stsm.model(model = "llm+seas", y = llmseas)
res <- maxlik.fd.scoring(m = m, step = NULL, 
  information = "expected", control = list(maxit = 100, tol = 0.001))
comps <- tsSmooth(res)
sse1 <- comps$states[,1] + 1.96 * comps$sse[,1]
sse2 <- comps$states[,1] - 1.96 * comps$sse[,1]
par(mfrow = c(2, 1), mar = c(3,3,3,3))
plot(ts.union(comps$states[,1], sse1, sse2), ylab = "", plot.type = "single", type = "n")
polygon(x = c(time(comps$states), rev(time(comps$states))), y = c(sse2, rev(sse1)), col = "lightgray", border = NA)
lines(comps$states[,1])
mtext(side = 3, text = "fitted level and 95% confidence interval", adj = 0)
plot(sse2 - sse1, plot.type = "single", ylab = "", type = "b", lty = 2, pch = 16)
mtext(side = 1, line = 2, text = "Time")
mtext(side = 3, text = "width of confidence interval in the top plot", adj = 0)
```

[image: sample confidence intervals for evenly recorded data]

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks for the clarification. I did not realize that the data was irregularly spaced so this make much more sense now! I appreciate that the larger error variances at the start and end of the state series (the state output from the Kalman filter and the smoother state) would lead to larger confidence intervals, but how are these intervals calculated? Specifically, can you provide a reference (or anything) that will show me how to implement the calculation of these varying confidence intervals?

Comment: Clearly the implementation for the Confidence Intervals I have above is not correct for such cases where the Kalman Filter Smoother is adopted. But what is the correct formula/algo. to use for the calculation of such intervals? Can the same formula take account of the case of irregularly spaced data (as in the case of the motorcycle data above)? If the same formula that is used to calculate the confidence intervals for the Kalman Filtered state cannot be used for the irregularly spaced data, what other formula can?

Comment: I really appreciate your time in helping me here, if you can expand your answer to encapsulate the question on the formulation of the calculation of the confidence intervals I will award the biggest bounty I can to you (which isn't much at this point!). Again, thanks.

Comment: Once you have your model written in state space form and given a set of parameters, the state smoothing recursions provide an estimate of the state vector given the observed data. The variance of the smoothed vector can also be obtained recursively. Upon these elements, it is straightforward to compute confidence intervals as the smoothed state vector plus and minus two times the corresponding standard deviations at each time point. This is what I did in the example above for the local level plus seasonal model.

Comment: To get an idea of how equations the smoother look like, you may see Appendix A in [this document](http://www.jalobe.com:8080/doc/stsm-em.pdf) available online. But I recommend you to study some textbook on this issue, e.g. Durbin and Koopman (2001) _Time Series Analysis by State Space Methods_ or Harvey (1989) _Forecasting, Structural Time Series Models and the Kalman Filter_. Chapter 2 of the first reference is a good place to start, the Kalman filter and smoother is derived for the local-level model, which is easier to handle as the state space form involves scalars instead of matrices.

Comment: Thank you. I have a Kalman Filter and Disturbance Smoother implemented ("filter/smoother"). This is done for the most generic state space model and can handle N-Dimensional state vectors. My problem come my understanding of the more simple statistical methods which are assumed to be known, whereas the more complex stuff is explicitly stated [hence I can implement]. Because I do not have a statistics background, easy things like confidence interval calculations for such state space models are unknown to me. Why is it 2x the stddev at each time point and what interval is given by 2x stddev?

Comment: When you say "smoothed state vector plus and minus two times the corresponding standard deviations at each time point" do you mean the stddev of the smoothed state series? Why have you use a factor of 1.96 in your R code above? Thanks very much for your time, it is most appreciated. I have just realized that you have updated your answer, please forgive me if you have already answered my questions...

Comment: I meant the _standard errors_ of the smoothed state series, which are obtained by the recursions of the smoother. I used the factor $\pm1.96$ to obtain the 95% confidence interval because it is the quantile 0.975 of the Gaussian distribution, the distribution assumed for the innovation terms in the model that I used as example. In practice there shouldn't be much difference rounding the factor to 2.

Comment: Thanks again, very helpful. I understand I can use the Inverse Cumulative Distribution function (quantile function) at some value q to get the q^(th) quantile of a distribution. But when I do this for the Normal distribution and calculate InvCDF(0.975) I get the value ~ 1.96; and for InvCDF(0.95) ~ 1.65, this is part way there... My question now is, how can I map my probability input values (i.e. the 0.975 and 0.95 which I input to the InvCDF) to my desired confidence intervals without the need for table lookup? I apologies for the basic questions here, but Google is failing me...

Comment: See the functions `dnorm`, `pnorm` and `qnorm` for the density, distribution function and quantile function for the normal distribution. For questions not related to the original post please make a new post, if the question is related to the usage of R functions you may post it at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Hi, I have asked a new question here. It is a simple one, but getting the information is proving difficult... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131482/how-to-map-desired-confidence-interval-to-a-quantile-value