# Visually representing confidence and standard deviation in a time series

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

We've been tasked with presenting a time-series graph showing 2 series of estimations each with a standard deviation and confidence. There are only 4-5 points in each series and both occur over the same time range (and might be very close in value/STD/confidence).

Can anyone recommend best practices for graphically representing this kind of data?

Comment: What do you intend by "a confidence"? Can you describe it more precisely?

Comment: What about the graph shown in this question? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131312/why-is-the-confidence-interval-changing-for-this-time-series

Comment: Do you have access to color in the final medium of presentation?